# Twilio Fax: Schema validation warning - 12200

Tags: php, laravel-5, twilio

**My Controller Code for incoming fax:**

```
$twimlResponse = new \SimpleXMLElement("<Response></Response>");
$recieveEl = $twimlResponse->addChild('Receive');
$recieveEl->addAttribute('action', '/api/fax/received/file');       
return response($twimlResponse->asXML(), 200)
      ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

**Output of my incoming web hook defined by above code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Response>
    <Receive action="/api/fax/received/file"/>
</Response>
```

**Twilio Error Log (Warning message)**

```
Msg: XML Validation warning
line: 2
parserMessage: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Receive'. One of '{Play
ErrorCode:12200
cols:79
LogLevel:WARN
url:http://......./api/fax/incoming
```

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/fax/quickstart#allow-twilio-to-talk-to-your-web-application

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/fax/receive

Comment: "When Twilio receives a call to an Incoming Phone Number that has been configured as a Fax number, you will receive an HTTP request to the FaxUrl configured for that number.".  Is that what's happening here to trigger that error?

Comment: Thanks @PatrickQ, Understood the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Twilio Configuration mismatch.**
I got the problem based on comment of @Patrick Q, I look at my numbers and I had 10 phone numbers among them in few numbers I forgot to change the configuration as below. I realized that phone numbers must be configured as **Fax numbers** and solved my problem.

**Problem with my few phone numbers** (created for Fax)
[image]

**Solution (Configured with fax)**
[image]

Thanks **Patrick Q**

Comment: Is there a way to do this via the REST API when creating new or updating an existing a incoming number?

Comment: Nevermind. I found it. For anyone else looking: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/fax/receive#phone-number-setup

Comment: oh wow cool, i will look at the link and see what you are saying to configure a phone number